# How to do basic authentication with Prowser using e-mail address-based usernames?

Tags: java, http, authentication

I am using [Prowser](http://prowser.sourceforge.net/) to screen scrape internal corporate websites.  Some of the sites use basic authentication where the username is:

username@corp.com

According to the documentation, in order to user digest or basic auth, I need to open the URL like this:

https://username:password@site.com/

But when I actually construct the URL, it looks like this:

https://username@corp.com:password@site.com/

Which results in a URI parse error.  I haven't been able to find any other way to do this using Prowser.  Is there a way to set these values manually in, eg. the Request object?  Or another way to encode the values?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are supposed to URI encode the username and password values, so "@" encodes to "%40".